# Authenticating DNS Queries

Tags: domain-name-system, authentication, bind, dnssec

Is there any way to use a TSIG (or other) key in combination with a DNS query to authenticate into a DNS view for use with recursion?  Something like:

```
key trusted-key {
    algorithm HMAC-SHA256;
    secret "blonggggg";
};

acl trusted { key trusted-key; };

view trusted {
    match-clients { trusted; };
    allow-recursion { any; };
};
```

If so, how would the querying client go about specifying the key for authentication?  What if it can be guaranteed that the queries are always coming from a downstream DNS server providing local caching DNS for a branch office?  Can the downstream DNS server be configured to use a particular key with all of the queries it's forwarding to the upstream server?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not believe you can configure DNS clients with TSIG (or other) keys. How do you plan on distributing the key and preventing others from using your key also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **testing** purposes, you could just use `dig -k ...` or `dig -y ...`.

For client machines to do this directly, I do not think it's viable. I'm not aware of any OS having a stub resolver that actually does TSIG signing.

However, it is possible to have a forwarding nameserver which uses TSIG to sign the forwarded queries.

You could do something like this (possibly on both ends, depending on the scenario):

```
key trusted-key {
    algorithm HMAC-SHA256;
    secret "x";
};

server 192.0.2.1 {
    keys { trusted-key.; };
};
```

This will cause BIND to always use the specified key to sign queries to the other server (identified by IP).

From the [`server` section in the manual](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#server_statement_grammar):

> The **keys** clause identifies a **key_id** defined by the key statement, to be used for transaction security (TSIG, [the section called “TSIG”](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.11/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch04.html#tsig)) when talking to the remote server. When a request is sent to the remote server, a request signature will be generated using the key specified here and appended to the message. A request originating from the remote server is not required to be signed by this key.
>
> Only a single key per server is currently supported.

Comment: I guess for mobile clients, I can run a local caching-only DNS that forwards all queries to the central server and authenticates with TSIG.  Thanks.